# How to access previous view controller from a dismiss command

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Throughout my app I use a navigation controller to push and pop my view controllers. When I pop from one ViewController, I check to see if I can reload the data in the previous one with this:

`_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
 if let previousViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as? AnimalsVC {
        previousViewController.tableView.reloadData()
 }`

This works every time, but now I need to do the same with another view, but it's not apart of the navigation controller because I modally present (instead of pushing it to the navigation controller). Now there's no way I can access the previous ViewController like before and I can not figure out how to access the previous ViewController.

**How can I access the previous ViewController to reload the tableview like the example code without accessing the navigation controller?**

*I know this is possible with notifications, but I prefer not to use that method if possible!*

Comment: Use a delegation pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, It's not necessary to access the previous ViewController to reload tableview(or any other func)

I recommend you to use **Delegate** to achieve the same feature.

Holding a reference to the previous viewController in the way you mentioned will make your app very hard to maintain when your app gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can call tableview.reloadData() in viewWillAppear method in the controller that you present modally